# How to make "Count in angularjs or lodash"

Tags: angularjs, lodash

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP2CQ.jpg][1]

[image]

You can see in image. I want to write count for this array. red box is analytic for attr of objects in array. i tried count Present,Late,Leave,...when list item checked with present or Late or Leave,...
How to count them. Please help code in angularjs or lodash. Thank you!

```
$scope.CountStudents = _.countBy($scope.Students, 'length');
console.log($scope.CountStudents);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not very clear about what exactly your problem is (besides learning AngularJS and Lodash ;-) ) and surely omitted a lot of required information.

However, just guessing:
With [lodash's `filter()` function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter) you can excerpt only those elements of a list that match a condition:

```
$scope.countAbsent = _.filter(students, {AbsentStatus: 'whatever'}).length;
```

To give you the number of students with 'whatever' as the AbsentStatus.

Comment: exactly, i want to count status of list item and show number at bottom page. That is: Present, Absent,Late, Leave,Oveseas status in capture image. I want to write function count them in Angularjs

Comment: Fine, then you know how to do it now! (Don't forget to accept the answer!)